# Как добавить ID пользователя с автоинкрементом golang + mongodb

Tags: golang, mongodb, autoincrement

Я хочу при добавлении пользователя в базу данных MongoDB делать автоинкремент UID.
MongoDB драйвер mgo.v2

```
type User struct {
  ID     bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
  UID    int           `bson:"uid" json:"uid"`
  Name   string        `bson:"name" json:"name"`
  Email  string        `bson:"email" json:"email"`
}

func (m *MusicDAO) InsertUser(user User) error {
  change := mgo.Change{
      Update:    bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"uid": 1}},
      ReturnNew: true,
  }

  // вот тут 2 ошибки
  // 1 - cannot assign *mgo.ChangeInfo to user (type model.User) in multiple assignment
  // 2 - undefined: M
  user, err := db.C(USER_COLLECTION).Find(M{"_id": user.ID}).Apply(change, &user)

  err = db.C(USER_COLLECTION).Insert(user)
  return err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте [пост](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb) в блоге MongoDB.